# There is no Internal Microphone option in my Mac system preference

Tags: macos-catalina, microphone

My Macbook Pro mic was working normally but there is a system hang so I have to restore and install new OS Catalina.
However I find out that the mic is not working, when I check in setting, it is not showing signal as I speak.
I search around Google but there is no one have the same issue with me: there is no  ‘Internal Microphone’ option in Sound setting.
Please refer to the below images:
[image]
[image]
Could you please give me some advice, thank you!